# Proving that if $|G| > 1$, then every irreducible $FG$-module has dimension $<|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

I think that the thing stopping me from solving this is that I don't fully understand the relationship between $FG$-modules and $F$-vector spaces. I believe $FG$-modules are in correspondence with representations $\psi: G \rightarrow GL_n(F)$, but to be honest I don't know how to interpret $GL_n(F)$. It's the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices over $F$, but I don't see where $n$ comes in.

Can someone give me some direction?

Comment: Wait, are you sure?

Comment: @Randall . Sorry, small mistake with $<$ in the title

Comment: Ahh, that's better.

Comment: See Problem $4$ [here](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~jblasiak/ProblemSet7Math533Winter15.pdf), and the solution sheet on the homepage.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is there a solution sheet there somewhere? (I couldn't find it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. Let $M$ be an irreducible $FG$ module, that means $M$ an $F$ vector space equipped with a left linear action of $G$ such that it has no non trivial submodule. Let $m \in M$ be a non zero vector. Because of $M$ irreducible , the span of $gm$ for all $g \in G$ is the entire $M$...

Comment: That only gives you $\leq$.

Comment: Yes ,i was try lo leaving the strict part not answered. The answer is kinda incomplete but it was meant to be just an hint

Comment: Suppose $\dim M=|G|$. Then $\{gm:g\in G\}$ is a basis. Take $N=\text{Span}\{\sum_{g\in G}gm\}$, a $G$-stable subspace of dimension 1. Contradiction. Note that we needed it to be a **basis** or else we may have $N=0$.

Answer (score 3):

For a field $F$ and a finite group $G$, $R=F[G]$ is a quasi-Frobenius ring, and in particular, $R_R$ contains a copy of every simple right $R$ module.

(Actually, the more specific relevant condition is that it is a left and right [Kasch ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasch_ring).)

Since $F[G]$ is $|G|$ dimensional, the dimension of any such copy would have to be less or equal.

Now since $F[G]$ is Artinian, it has finite composition length. A composition series can start at any one of these simple submodules. Now, the only way for $\dim(S)=|G|$ for one of these simple submodules is if the compostion length is $1$: but that would mean $F[G]$ is a simple $F[G]$ module, implying that it is a field. But when $|G|>1$, the augmentation ideal of $F[G]$ is always nonzero, so it is only a field when $|G|=1$.

Thus if $|G|>1$, $F[G]$ has composition length $>1$, and therefore $S\neq F[G]$ and has strictly smaller dimension.

Comment: The OP is looking for strict inequality.

Comment: @DavidHill Ah, good point... I think I can accommodate that.

Comment: One irreducible module is already known---the trivial representation.  So, any other irreducible module must be of dimension at most $|G|-1$.

Comment: @DavidHill I provided one way of thinking about it: thanks for letting me know about this lacuna.